# Need to search for a specific element in xml file via jenkins pipeline

Tags: xml, jenkins, xpath, xmlstarlet

I have the following xml file

```
<versions>
    <version>1.0.1</version>
    <version>1.0.2</version>
    <version>1.0.3</version>
</versions>
```

now I have a created a string parameter called "version_to_read" in jenkins put it in a variable var="{params.version_to_read}"

with the above variable it is able to read the value from the user as an input from jenkins pipeline, but in order to search for the same value inside the xml file I am using the command

var2=sh(returnStdout: true, script: 'xmlstarlet sel -t -v "(/version[.='${var}'])" -n < maven-metadata.xml')

but it gives the error "Invalid predicate: (/version[.='${var}'])"

but the same xmlstarlet command works fine on command prompt but not working from jenkins side

Can anyone give suggestion on this. Very confused with the commands which are working fine on linux command prompt but the same command not working on jenkins

I need to get only a specific value given from the jenkins pipeline string parameter, it should search in the xml file and display

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems here.

The first is the XPath `/version` needs to be `/versions/version` since you are starting from `/` which represents the document, and the root element is `versions`.

The other problem is not an XPath problem but a shell string-substitution problem.

Your XPath expression includes single quotes, and so the shell string-substitution expression embedded in those quotes is not interpreted. The single quotes have the effect of including that `${var}` as literal text in the XPath expression.

Try this instead: NB here the single quotes enclose all of the XPath expression *except* for the variable itself.

```
xmlstarlet sel -t -v '(/versions/version[.="'${var}'"])'
```

Comment: Hi Conal, thanks for your suggestion, but this command also shows syntax errors through jenkins pipeline.  Where //versions/version[text( )]  shows all the values. Now I am trying to read each value from this using a variable